# How do I use my mulligans?

Tags: mario-golf-world-tour

In Mario Golf: World Tour's Castle Club mode, I purchased the ability to mulligan my shots from Kamek in the Royal Garden for 10,000 coins. However, when I later whiffed a shot during a tournament I couldn't find said mulligan option.

How do I mulligan a shot after purchasing the ability from Kamek?

[image: Buying a mulligan from Kamek]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off of [this Game FAQ](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/704056-mario-golf-world-tour/69165587) post, you can't use them in tournaments and VS mode.  Besides that though, the game seems to prompt you if you have any available after *every* shot, which some find annoying:

> Not tournaments and not vs. mode, namely.
>
> The game will give you the option if they can be used. Keep in mind that, if you choose to have them available, you'll be asked on EVERY SINGLE SHOT whether you want to continue or use a mulligan

Comment: Confirming mulligans work outside of tournaments. It even works outside of Castle Club when playing as non-Mii characters.